# Learning Mono Source Code

Tags: c#, mono, open-source

I am interested in contributing something to mono whether it is a documentation or what ever. As a first step, I downloaded the source tree for going through the code. However, I thought if some one would've spend enough time to understand the project structure that would help everyone here. Any one point me out where the project structure is well explained?

NOTE: This is not a duplicate of question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655090/mono-source-code-walkthrough-tutorial, the answer to this question doesn't suffice my expectation.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should have [checked out](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/) (*subversion* checkout URLs [here](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/)):

- **trunk/libgdiplus**

  This is a library used by System.Drawing.
- **trunk/mono**

  This is what we call the Mono **runtime**. Contains mainly C source code. Under this directory you can find:

  - **data/**: a few configuration files for different version (1.x, 2.x,...).
  - **msvc*/**: Visual Studio solution files to build the Mono runtime.
  - **libgc/**: the Boehm Garbage Collector sources.
  - **mono/**: Mono runtime sources.

    - **mini/**: JIT source code
    - **metadata/**: these are almost all the functions used by the Mono runtime (marshaling, thread pool, socket I/O, file I/O, console I/O, application domains, GC, performance counters,...). It's more or less one C file each.
    - **util**: miscellaneous functions.
    - **io-layer/**: Win32 I/O emulation functions.
- **trunk/mcs**

  This is where the C# compiler, the **class libraries**, class libraries tests and other tools are.

  - **class/** : One folder per assembly. Each of them contains the source code for each assembly split in directories with the namespace name (ie, *System/System.Configuration* and so on) and usually a Test directory too. The only naming exception is **mscorlib** whose corresponding folder is called **corlib**.

    For example, if you want to see the source code for *System.Net.HttpWebRequest*, which is in the *System.dll* assembly, you go to *trunk/mcs/class/System/System.Net* and there shoould be a file named *HttpWebRequest.cs* containing the code you're looking for.
  - **mcs/**: the sources for the C# compilers (mcs, gmcs, smcs, dmcs...)
  - **tools/**: these are a bunch of tools used for development (sn, wsdl,...), documentation (monodoc), etc. Most of the tools names match the MS ones.

There are a lot more directories around, but those are where you should look for the C and C# code. Also, I suggested *trunk* for the checkout, since you will get the most up-to-date sources that way.

**Update:** Mono resides now in [github](http://github.com/mono) and *mcs* has been integrated into the *mono* repository.

Comment: Thank you very much for describing the directory structure, also do you know if there is a web site describing this?

Comment: There is https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 4):

Gonzalo provided a good overview of the different modules.

Since you also mentioned wanting to contribute to documentation, you'll want a few more pieces of information.

First, Documentation is stored in XML files within **mcs/class/[assembly]/Documentation/**, e.g. [mcs/class/corlib/Documentation](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/mcs/class/corlib/Documentation).  The intent is to support multiple human languages (though only English is currently being worked on), so within **Documentation** is a language directory, usually `en`.  Within `en` there are `ns-*.xml` files, e.g. [mcs/class/corlib/Documentation/en/ns-System.xml](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/mcs/class/corlib/Documentation/en/ns-System.xml) contains documentation for the `System` namespace.  Also within `en` are "dotted namespace" directories, and within those are XML files, one per type, for example [mcs/class/corlib/Documentation/en/System.Collections.Generic/IEnumerable`1.xml](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/mcs/class/corlib/Documentation/en/System.Collections.Generic/IEnumerable%60.xml).

This is also outlined within the [mdoc(5)](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=man:mdoc(5)) documentation, in the `FILE/DIRECTORY STRUCTURE` section.

Once you've found the documentation, you need to know the XML format, which is also described in the [mdoc(5)](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=man:mdoc(5)) documentation, in the `NamespaceName/TypeName.xml File Format` section.  The XML dialect used is a variant of the [ECMA 335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) [XML documentation](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.zip), changed to have one file per type (instead of all types within a single monolithic file).  This is also a superset of [C# XML documentation](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) (see `Annex E. Documentation Comments`, page 487).

Finally, there's the question of adding new types/members to the **mcs/class/[assembly]/Documentation** directory.  If you have Mono built, you can use the `doc-update` Makefile target.  This will run the appropriate assembly through [mdoc(1)](http://www.mono-project.com/Mdoc) and update the appropriate files within the **Documentation** directory.

If you have any other documentation questions, don't hesitate to ask on the [mono-docs-list](http://lists.ximian.com/mailman/listinfo/mono-docs-list) mailing list.