# What language is Mono written in and how do I read the source code?

Tags: c#, mono, clr

I want to read the source code for Mono. I looked up this URL and there are several folders  [here](http://download.mono-project.com/sources/).

1. What language is the Mono project written in?
2. Which folder/file do I download to read its source?

From looking at the folder hierarchy, it appears (although my assumption could be wrong) that it has been written in several languages and that I could download any one of them.

But I'd just like to make sure.

Comment: [Here is an overview of the folders.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1912716/1106367).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want the mono subdirectory, pick the version you are interested in.

The equivalent of the CLR and the jitter were written in C.  You'll find it in the mono/mini subdirectory.

The C# compiler was written in C#.  You'll find it in the mcs/mcs subdirectory.

The framework classes were written in C#.  You'll find them in the mcs/class subdirectories.

Comment: Thank you, Hans. 

Sorry if my question sounds stupid. How could the C# compiler have been written in C#?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2: GCC's C compiler is also written in C.

Comment: They bootstrapped it through another C# compiler.  The Microsoft one, probably.  It was written in C++.

Comment: @PabloSantaCruz I am not debating the comment. I am just curious. In the case you mention, I understand that the same language compiler from another vendor might have been used to write a new compiler for the language. In the case of C#, however, even though the C# language specification is released by Microsoft and EMCA, the C# compiler itself is proprietary. What would have been the need of writing a C# compiler if the MSFT C# compiler already worked in the target environment?

Comment: As noted, the Microsoft C# compiler was written in C++.  So it runs only on a select few target platforms.

Comment: Now it appears that there is no /trunk/mcs folder. At least I can't find one. Can someone help me find it?

Comment: There isn't.  It is inside of the tar.bz2 file after you expand it.  Use a tool like 7-zip to expand the file.

Comment: I'd downloaded the version 2.4.2 http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/mono-2.4.2.tar.bz2 file and unzipped it, but even in that, there was no such folder hierarchy.

Comment: I checked, it is there.  mono-2.4.2\mcs\ directory.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, C#. There is a page on the Mono website that talks about the various languages. So look here: [MonoProject - Languages](http://mono-project.com/Languages)

Comment: I think OP is asking what the mono project itself is written in, not what language you write mono projects in. If so, the answer would be C (I believe), not C#.

Comment: @flem: mono C# compiler is indeed written in C#.

Comment: ++@flem. That page Marc pointed to is not very well written and does not answer my question either.